# IDFA related warning in validating iOS APP?

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, ads

I added "Google admob" to one of my apps("admob" is compulsory in app), and when i tried to validate, it's giving me a warning. Please check the screen shot[image]

I really don't know what to do now, can somebody please explain to me the process to clear that warning and upload this to app store?

These are the frameworks I am using.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with you code, but with the apps configuration on iTunesConnect.

We preparing the app for upload there was a question if you are using the advertisement identifier. Which as answered with no.

Since Apple no longer allows the user of the advertisement identifier with showing ads you cannot upload an app where somewhere in the code the advertisement identifier is called.

If you app does not show an ad you can not call the advertisement identifier, which admob is doing.